# How to hide or remove gaps in Grafana time series graph for periods with no data?

Tags: grafana

I'm currently using Grafana for visualizing my data in a time series graph. My data is collected daily from 9 AM to 3 PM. The next day, data collection continues from 9 AM to 3 PM again. However, when I plot these two sets of data on a time series graph, there is a large gap from 3 PM on the first day to 9 AM on the second day. This is because I don't collect data during this time period.

My question is: Is there a way in Grafana to only display the time periods where I have data? In other words, can I exclude the time period from 3 PM to 9 AM where I don't have any data from the time series graph?

Thank you in advance for your help.

I've tried going through the Grafana documentation and also used Grafana's solution for handling null values, but none of these approaches have solved my problem

Comment: No. There is no such possibility.

Comment: The best you can do, is to specify dashboard time range as something like `now/d+9h`, `now/d-9h`, and add two panels with your data: one as is, one with time shift set to 24h